# Regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, decimal

The below code is to validate any input of decimal type with a precision of 2.

```
function check() {
    var str = $('#txttest').val();
    var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");
    var res = patt.test(str);
    alert(res);
}
```

**Valid examples:**

- 12
- 12.00
- 12.00a
- 12a
- a12
- 1a2.00

**Failed Case:**

In some cases, the function is returning wrong values, like **1a2**.

Now, please suggest.

Comment: 2 issues: 1) double the backslash or use a regex literal, 2) add a `$` at the end. Try `var patt = /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;`

Comment: yes. I have correct my code snippet.

Comment: Well, you say all those cases under "Valid examples" are valid, but [only two match](https://regex101.com/r/zYcF4p/2).

Comment: but in my sample application, all are working :( except the failed one, 1a2

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew,  i have replaced 'new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$")' with '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/' and its working. could you please explain the reason . Thanks.

Comment: `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/` is a RegExp literal, which is why it is working. Your quoted string is not working because inside quotes you need to escape your backslash: `new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$")`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JavaScript's [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) method?

Comment: I want to validate the input.

Comment: @SagnikMukherjee so? Just check `Number(input) == Number(input).toFixed(2)` - if they match, then it was the same number by definition. Not much need for a regex.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try your solution.  But my question is why the expression is failing.